# A way to contract input in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

If I input a giant matrix in Mathematica, and it is contained in a cell, is there a way to contract it so that it uses up significantly less space in the notebook?

Comment: If I understand you right, you can always put ";" at the end so it does not display (i.e. make an OUT cell). Otherwise look at [Short](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) command which will display a small version of the input.

Comment: ... Ofcourse, you can always turn off the Open property of the Input CELL also.

Comment: How about just fold the cell? Group the cells and fold the group.

Comment: Also look at `Shallow` and `Skeleton` commands.

Comment: `Iconize` might be what you're looking for!

Comment: The input is the problem, all I can see to do is make the font tiny, but it's still enormous.

Comment: As @CarlLange was suggesting, `Iconinze` might be the way to go: Select the matrix, right click and select "Un/Iconize selection" or similar. This should collapse the matrix into a tiny box

Comment: I use this trick specially when initializing variables to a very long string: select the cell and then from the menus: Format→Word Wrapping→Don't word wrap

Comment: You do not say what is inside your matrix. Real numbers can be rounded to one digit for printing, sparse matrix can be represented as a list of nonzero elements. Finally,instead of printing a matrix, you may print its norm, or some other properties that characterize it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From comments, these are the two options

Use cell/open/close

[image]

Use Iconize, as suggested by Carl Lange, which I think is a better option, since you still see the LHS of the assignment and so know what is one that cell, as compared to open/close the cell, where you'd have to open the cell again to see what is there.

[image]

Comment: You can also call Iconize in code with a second argument to give the pill a label, FYI!

Comment: I also like the iconize option much better.  Also, you can iconize just a portion of the matrix.  This might not be so interesting for matrices, but it's very interesting for other inputs.  For example, a `Plot` command that has its function and range in the open, but a sequence of messy options iconized.